# How to send a single mail using drewM/mailchimp-api package, without subscribing in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

This is what I have done:

```
$mailChimp = new MailChimp('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$mailChimp->from('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$mailChimp->reply_to('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$mailChimp->to(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
$mailChimp->subject('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$mailChimp->message($message);
$mailChimp->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
$mailChimp->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
$mailChimp->mailtype('html');
```

I'm getting an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mailchimp php integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565170/mailchimp-php-integration)

Comment: No, that link giving an error

Comment: What error? Could you please attach as much info as you can?